# Sass @extend to consider imported css during build

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, extend, vue-cli-3

I have a global CSS file that contains all generic CSS.

I want to be able to extend all the classes present in this global CSS file in any of my SCSS files.

Right now it throws an error .xyz class does not exist and build fails. I tried importing this file but still build fails.

Adding !options next to class is one way for the build to pass but is there any other better way?

Bit more context for Vue users. I use VueCli3. I use `<style lang="scss">` for writing SCSS and want to use extend here.  [Vue documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders) suggesting adding prependData for adding variables. I imported the global CSS in a SCSS file and imported that file in the prependData but Vue build still fails.

Comment: I didn't get you. But What I understand you want to extends your css file class into sass structure right?

Comment: yes. I want SCSS to consider the CSS class from an external file and all the classes inside that external file should be used by @extend key of SCSS.

Comment: Okay I understand. Please check my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using @import CSS file into SCSS file not possible to @extend any class.

But you can follow below steps for extends class from your pure css code.

1. Convert `.css` file into `.scss`.
2. import that `global.scss` file into another `.scss` file.
3. Then after you can use @extend for extend class in new file.

If your file have more then 1k line of code then it will get trouble for extend class.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to globally include a CSS file with content that the SCSS blocks in each component can read. (Variables, style definitions, etc).

`@extend` works like a variable, meaning SCSS needs the definition style to be available as part of its compilation. So that means getting "SCSS Global Variables" working should solve your Extend problem too.

In that case, you need to tweak how Webpack deals with your components. You can do it manually as described [here](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/globally-load-sass-into-your-vue-js-applications/). Or my preference is to use a Vue Cli plugin called [vue-cli-plugin-sass-resources-loader](https://github.com/Liaoct/vue-cli-plugin-sass-resources-loader#readme). Make sure that your component `<style>` section contains `lang="SCSS"` though I assume you're already doing that.

Comment: But in that case, I would have to bring in my entire SCSS setup just to use extend right? Technically @extend brings all the CSS elements of extending class and appends and forms a new class. It need not have variables and mixins and other SCSS stuff, right? So is there no other way than to bring the SCSS build setup into the project?